# Why is Xilinx ILA's clock frequency required to be at least twice of that of JTAG?

Tags: xilinx, jtag

In various places, it's mentioned that the frequency of the clock input to ILA module has to be at least 2.5x of JTAG frequency, otherwise ILA may not work properly.

Out of curiosity, I am wondering why that is.

PS: UG908 (v2023.1) pp163-166 have some information regarding the clocks' relationship. According to Figure 94 on page 166, it seems that the "Debug Hub" needs to sample the serial data from BSCAN, thus the 2.5x relationship. This is based on the assumption that `TCK` does not drive the receiving logic of "Debug Hub" for receiving TDI.

For sending data out over TDO, I guess the "Debug Hub" needs to use TCK. Why it does not also use the TCK for receiving TDI?

So another possibility is that, TCK is used for both TDI/TDO, and the 2.5x relationship has nothing to do with sampling TDI. It's an empirical rule which works in most circumstances for Debug Hub relaying data between JTAG and several debug cores.

Comment: I found [63292 - Vivado 2014.4 - Logic Debug - Digilent Cable at 20Mhz ILA not Triggering](https://support.xilinx.com/s/article/63292?language=en_US) which contains ``When trying to trigger a design with a frequency clock slower than 2.5x the JTAG clock frequency, the ILA does not trigger.``. Not yet sure if the limitation only applies to triggering or other ILA functionality.

Comment: I would guess that it has something to do with how the JTAG signals (which are used to read out the ILA) are brought into the ILA's clock domain.